# What to put as condition in while loop?

Tags: java, random, methods, while-loop, numbers

I am writing a method that prints `guesses = [random number here from 1-50 inclusive]` multiple times on a new line until the value is larger than 48. Once it is larger than 48 I try to print the number of guesses it took (No scanner used though, the 'guesses' are the number produced by the Math.random). 
Here is example output:

```
guess = 43
guess = 47
guess = 45
guess = 27
guess = 49
total guesses = 5
```

and this is my output:

```
guess = 44
guess = 47
guess = 45
guess = 27
total guesses = 4
```

The reason I am getting almost the same random numbers is because it's in Practice-It.

Here is my code:

```
public static void makeGuesses(){
    int totalGuesses = 0;
    double randomNumber = (Math.random() * 50 + 1);

    while(randomNumber < 48){
        System.out.print("guess = ");
        System.out.println(randomNumber + 1); 
        randomNumber = (int)(Math.random() * 51);
        totalGuesses++;
    }
        System.out.print("total guesses = " + totalGuesses);   
}
```

Currently, I am not getting the last line of required output. What do I need to make the condition on my while loop?

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track in that you need to cast to `int`, but you need to cast to int when you *generate* the number.

Furthermore, if you use your current implementation, you are generating numbers from 0-50, inclusive. You want to generate from 1-50, inclusive. You can fix this by multiplying by 50, then simply adding 1.

```
int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 50 + 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first `random` isn't an `int` because you forgot the cast

```
double randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 51);
```

I suggest you make the type an `int` as well

```
int randomNumber = (int) (Math.random() * 51);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you need to generate random numbers again and again, you should use `java.util.Random` for this.

```
    public static void makeGuesses() {
        int totalGuesses = 0;
        Random rdm = new Random();
        int randomNumber;
        do {
            randomNumber = rdm.nextInt(50) + 1;
            System.out.println("guess = " + randomNumber);
            totalGuesses++;
        } while (randomNumber < 48);
        System.out.println("total guesses = " + totalGuesses);
    }
}
```

**Output :**

```
guess = 15
guess = 29
guess = 26
guess = 14
guess = 3
guess = 1
guess = 49
total guesses = 7
```

Comment: It is not clear. Which last line. "total guesses = ..." will be printed.

Comment: "guess = 49". I am pretty sure it's my while loop test that I need to change...?

Comment: If you want to know all the random numbers that are generated, then you should use `do-while` for this. I have edited my answer. have a look at that.

Comment: It's still not printing the last line... I want it to print the number that's bigger than 48 once, and then stop there, and return the totalGuesses

Comment: You must be doing mistake somewhere else. Now I have also posted output of a test run.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the condition on your while checks a number you have not yet printed. If you use a debugger and step through the code, you will notice this.

```
int totalGuesses = 0;
int randomNumber;

while (true) {
  randomNumber = 1 + (int)Math.floor(Math.random() * 50);
  totalGuesses += 1;
  System.out.print("guess = ");
  System.out.println(randomNumber);
  if (randomNumber > 48) break;
}

System.out.print("total guesses = " + totalGuesses);
```

Sorry I can't format code well on my phone.